# fetch_feed: retrieve entries in the appearing order, not chronologically

Tags: php, json, feed, simplepie

I'm using WP function fetch_feed to retrieve a feed and display its items.

```
    <?php
    /* include the required file */     include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
    /* specify the source feed   */     $rss = fetch_feed('FEED_URL');
    /* checks obj. is created    */     if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
    /* specify number of items   */     $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
    /* create an array of items  */     $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>Content not available.</li>';
    else
        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>" rel="external"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

If I visit the [feed in question](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1342772) with (e.g.) Firefox, I see the entries in the XML appearing order. fetch_feed retrieves the most recent instead (according to their "published" tag). How can I make sure it retrieves items according to their order on the XML feed (not chronologically).
Maybe is possible to set the order with [this](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/sort_items)..?

**EDIT:** I tried adding $feed->enable_order_by_date(false); but it seems to break the function..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found. I spent hours on this but I managed to find the solution.
The command I was looking for was $rss->enable_order_by_date(false);.

So you should set (for benefit of the community):

```
    <?php
    /* include the required file */     include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
    /* specify the source feed   */     $rss = fetch_feed('FEED_URL');
    /* disable order by date     */     $rss->enable_order_by_date(false);
    /* checks obj. is created    */     if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
    /* specify number of items   */     $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(X);
    /* create an array of items  */     $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>Content not available.</li>';
    else
        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>" rel="external"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Good for you. You can choose your own answer as the correct answer (and maybe explain why when you added it before, it broke the function)

Comment: It broke when I used $feed->enable_order_by_date(false);. It worked with $rss->enable_order_by_date(false); ($rss instead of $feed). :)
I can accept my answer in two days.